# Java неправильно калькулирует?

Tags: java

Села изучать Java и уже с первых дней появился совершенно непонятный вопрос: почему два одинаковых на первый взгляд выражения дают разный результат?

System.out.println (850 / 100 * 15.0); **Ответ: 120.0**
System.out.println (850 * 0.15); **Ответ 127.5**

*Но если уменьшить первое число, то ответы возвращаются одинаковые:*

System.out.println (800 / 100 * 15.0); **Ответ: 120.0**
System.out.println (800 * 0.15); **Ответ 120.0**

Comment: *Но если уменьшить первое число, то ответы возвращаются одинаковые:* - не поэтому. А если первое число делится без остатка на второе.

Comment: Это Вы еще на 0.0 не делили

Comment: все правильно, только так и не сказали, как это исправить)) System.out.println (850 / 100D * 15.0);

Answer (score 5):

Выражение

```
850 / 100 * 15.0
```

вычисляется по шагам:

```
1. __temp = 850 / 100
2. __temp * 15.0
```

В первом шаге оба операнда целые, значит результат тоже будет целым `__temp = 8`.